# PopupMenuButton sending Buildcontext to handleclick function

Tags: function, flutter, popupmenubutton

I am pretty new to flutter and I found the code for my PopupMenuButton online and modified it slightly. I want the logout option to run Navigator.pop(context), but I don't understand how to get it get it there.
Code:

```
PopupMenuButton<String>(
      onSelected: handleClick,
      itemBuilder: (context) {
      return {'Logout', 'Settings'}.map((String choice) {
        return PopupMenuItem<String>(
           value: choice,
        child: Text(choice)
      );
    }).toList();
  }
),
```

And I want to send it in here:

```
void handleClick(String value, BuildContext context) {
  switch (value) {
    case 'Logout':
      storage.deleteAll();
      //Navigator.pop();

      break;
    case 'Settings':
      break;
  }
}
```

I also tried making Buildcontext a global final late variable, but it seemed to cause a lot of problems.
To be honest, I don't understand how the PopupMenuButton works in regards to calling the funtion, thus me not knowing how to pass another argument
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Write `onSelected` like this instead:

```dart
onSelected: (value) {
  handleClick(value, context);
},
```

Comment: I don't understand that. How do I add the options logout and settings?

Comment: Instead of writing `onSelected: handleClick`, write it like I showed in the answer.